# How to remove a property during WriteJson

Tags: c#, json.net

I have created a test console application that has a simple class named Other.  As an exercise, I want to set the OtherString property to null when it is serialized.  I know how I could do this with a custom ContractResolver.  I need to be able to do this with a custom Converter too.

The first converter I wrote was simple and the way I thought it should be.  However, it would throw a "Self referencing loop detected with type 'JsonContractandConvert.Models.Other'. Path ''." exception.  After doing some reading, I made some changes and now I have a working converter.  These changes are a lot more verbose, but work.

My question is why are these changes required and is there a better way to do this with a Converter?

Other Class:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(OtherConverter))]
public class Other
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OtherString { get; set; }
    public int OtherInt { get; set; }

public string OtherName
    {
        get
        {
        return "Other Name = " + this.OtherString;
        }
    }
}
```

First Attempt: (This one throws an exception)

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    if (!this.CanConvert(value.GetType())) return;

    var entity = value as Other;
    if (entity == null) return;

    entity.OtherString = null;

    serializer.Serialize(writer, entity);
}
```

Second Attempt: (This works as expected)

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    if (!this.CanConvert(value.GetType())) return;

    var entity = value as Other;
    if (entity == null) return;

    entity.OtherString = null;

    writer.WriteStartObject();
    var props = entity.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (var propertyInfo in props)
    {
        var ignorAttribute =
            propertyInfo.CustomAttributes.FirstOrDefault(i => i.AttributeType == typeof(JsonIgnoreAttribute));

    if (ignorAttribute != null) continue;
                var tempVal = propertyInfo.GetValue(entity);
            if (tempVal == null) continue;

            writer.WritePropertyName(propertyInfo.Name);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, tempVal);
        }
    }
    writer.WriteEndObject();
}
```

Edit:

Here's the code from the console app that I'm using to test.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var otherObj = new Other { Id = 123, OtherInt = 456, OtherString = "This is the other string"};
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(otherObj, Formatting.Indented);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use simply `JsonIgnore`. what is the difference between `{a=1}` and `{a=1,b=null}`? At the reader site, both json will be converted to `b=null`

Comment: JsonIgnore would only work if you want to ignore it.  In the example above, if I set entity.OtherString = "Something else"; I get the same error.

Comment: `I get the same error`, What error? It is a simple serialization. `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj)` that's all. No need for any code(or any converter) in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own questions... (I think I've finally got my head around Json Converters)

To answer my basic question as to why one way works and the other doesn't.  I think the answer is just that the way that doesn't work is just wrong.  From what I can tell, you need to use the writer object.  If you don't it won't work. (There may be scenarios where this is not the case, but I never found one.)

If you merely want to remove a property from the Json, use [JsonIgnore]. (Simple right?)

If you want to change the value some how, you'll need to use a Converter.  By using a Converter, you're taking responsibility for serializing what ever object the Converter handles.  So if the object is a simple type like a String, or an Int it's really easy.  If it's something more complex like an array or complex object, then it takes a little more planning.

Here's an example of a simple String Converter:

Class to serialize:

```
public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Account DefaultAssignTo { get; set; }
    public int? DefaultAssignToId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Other Other { get; set; }
    public int? OtherId { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringConverter))]
    public string OtherName
    {
        get
        {
                return "Name = " + this.AccountName;
        }
    }
```

}

Converter:

```
public class StringConverter : JsonConverter
{        
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(string).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (!this.CanConvert(value.GetType())) return;

        writer.WriteValue("blah blah blah");    
    }
}
```

Run: (As you can see I'm using Entity Framework for my data)

```
using (var db = new Context())
{
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(db.Accounts.FirstOrDefault(), Formatting.Indented, 
        new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
    Console.WriteLine(json);
}
```

Returns:

```
{
  "Id": 43,
  "AccountName": "John",
  "DefaultAssignToId": 43,
  "OtherId": 19,
  "OtherName": "blah blah blah"
}
```

One of the things that messed me up for a bit was when to use writer.WriteStartObject().  Basically if you are Converting a complex object, you need to use it.  If you do, then you need to create all of the property names and values.  In the OP you can see an example of how I did this.  The biggest down side is any Json attributes that properties are decorated with don't automatically happen.  So if you can, decorate the class and let the serializer deal with it.  Here's an interesting problem you can run into if you use it wrong.

In the String converter replace:

```
writer.WriteValue("blah blah blah");
```

with:

```
writer.WriteStartObject();
writer.WritePropertyName("BlahProp");
serializer.Serialize(writer, "blah blah blah");
writer.WriteEndObject();
```

run it again and here's the output: (Notice how OtherName is an object now instead of a string)

```
{
  "Id": 43,
  "AccountName": "John",
  "DefaultAssignToId": 43,
  "OtherId": 19,
  "OtherName": {
    "BlahProp": "blah blah blah"
  }
}
```

The Roles collection also needed a Converter.  Two things to note are first, you don't need to specify the property name and second, any Json attributes that the Role class is decorated with will work as expected.

```
using BaseCollection = System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<JsonContractandConvert.Models.Role>;
public class RemoveAccountsFromRolesConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(BaseCollection).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (!this.CanConvert(value.GetType())) return;

        var entities = value as BaseCollection;
        if (entities == null) return;

        writer.WriteStartArray();
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
        entity.Accounts = null;
        serializer.Serialize(writer, entity);
        }
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }
}
```

Lastly, here's a couple of converters I created for my real project:

This one converts an object to a shallow copy.  This is useful if you have a collection where what that collection contains could cause a self referencing loop.

```
public class ShallowCopyCollectionConverter<TCollectionType, TCopyType> : JsonConverter
    where TCollectionType : IEnumerable<TbdEntity>
    where TCopyType : TbdEntity, new()
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(TCollectionType).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (this.CanConvert(value.GetType()) == false) return;

        var entities = (TCollectionType)value;
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, entity.ShallowCopy<TCopyType>()); //ShallowCopy<> is a method in the base class that all of my classes extend.
        }
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }
}
```

This one will convert an abstract using the concrete type:

```
public class DataSnapInConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(DataSnapIn) == (objectType);
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (this.CanConvert(objectType) == false) return null;

        var jo = JObject.Load(reader);
        var typeName = jo["snapInType"] ?? jo["SnapInType"];  //the abstract classes have this property to identify what concrete class they are.
        var typeNameString = typeName.ToString();

        var deserializeType = Type.GetType(typeNameString);
        if(deserializeType == null)
            throw new Exception("SnapInType is null or does not reference a valid class.");

        var result = Activator.CreateInstance(deserializeType);
        serializer.Populate(jo.CreateReader(), result);

        return result;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```